# Need to return more decimal places from a simple division operation

Tags: java

So I'm taking a java class and our projects are run through an autochecker.  The autochecker is giving me the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: When checking the return value of convertDistance(25724767,"Kilometers") we  
Expected :4.139989652378E7
Actual   :4.1399999E7
```

Here's the code it's referring to:

```
public static double convertDistance(long distance, String scale) {
            switch (scale) {
                case "Yards": distance *= 1760; break;
                case "Kilometers": distance *= 1.60934; break;
                case "Meters": distance *= 1609.34; break;
                case "Miles": break;
                default: distance = (long)0.0;
            }
        return distance;
        }
```

All the distances being passed into the method are given, as is the conversion, so I can't change those.  Can anyone tell me how I can force it to return those extra decimal places?  Thanks guys

Comment: Question makes no sense. A double is a double is a double. Problem would seem to be you're likely using `==` to check the value of a double (which is wrong).

Comment: You need to convert `distance` to a `double` variable first, and carry out the conversions on the `double`, and return it.

Comment: @John3136 The question makes plenty of sense; it's a `long`; and he isn't using `==` anywhere, let alone on doubles. What are you talking about?

Comment: I'm not using == for anything.  25724767 gets passed in as the long.  "Kilometers" gets passed in as the string.  The autochecker looks at the return value.  It says the return should be 4.139989652378E7, but it's 4.1399999E7

Comment: @user207421 Then it's even screwier: it tries to return a double but actually returns a long? There's your problem...

Comment: @user207421 I think I tried that already, but I will give it a go, thank you

Comment: @John3136 It's not my problem, it's the OP's, and I already gave that solution. You seem to have missed the part where this code is being executed by an autochecker, and that `long` can be automatically widened to `double`.

Comment: @clutzyninja You haven't tried it yet, otherwise you wouldn't be asking. Elliot's solution below is fully equivalent to my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distance` is a `long`, which you update in place (losing precision, because you multiply it by constant `double` values). Instead of storing temporary results, I suggest you return the result directly. Like,

```
public static double convertDistance(long distance, String scale) {
    switch (scale) {
        case "Yards": return distance * 1760;
        case "Kilometers": return distance * 1.60934;
        case "Meters": return distance * 1609.34;
        case "Miles": return distance;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That simplifies your code (and fixes it). Testing with your example input I get

```
4.139989652378E7
```

(as expected)

Comment: Also, could you elaborate a little?  To my untrained eye, it seems like *= and then returning would do the same thing as just returning the operation.  I get why it's more efficient to return from each case, but I don't get why the answer changes

Comment: @clutzyninja The problem is that the computation was evaluated as a `double` but then stored back into a `long`, which truncated its fractional part. Doing it this way it stays as a `double`.

Comment: @clutzyninja To elaborate further, if you had tried `distance = distance * 1.60934;` you would have seen a compiler error.

Comment: ... but you didn't with your code, because `*=` and friends have special rules.